# Solve quadratic, but only one solution allowed

Tags: calculus

Given: $x^2-mx+ma-a^2=0$

I tried to find the value of $m$, for which $x$ has **only one solution**. I solved it by calculating the discriminant:
$\sqrt{(-m)^2-4ma+4a^2}=0$ which gives $m=2a$

**Question:** Is there a simpler or different way to arrive at this conclusion?

My calculus book says: "In order that this quadratic have only one solution $x=a$ the left side must be $(x-a)^2$". However, I don't understand what is meant by this.

Comment: what exactly you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that putting $x=a$ in $p(x)=x^2-mx+ma-a^2$ gives zero. Hence $x=a$ is always a root of $p(x)$, and you can use the factor theorem to say that
$$p(x)=(x-a)q(x),$$
where $q(x)$ is some polynomial of lower degree than $q$. Staring at $p$ makes it clear that $q(x)$ has degree $1$, and if we look harder, we see it is of the form $(x-b)$ for some $b$. Expanding out,
$$ p(x)=(x-a)(x-b)=x^2-(a+b)x+ab, $$
and therefore we see that $a+b=m$, and $ab=ma-a^2$, which are both true when $b=m-a$. Hence the factorisation of $p$ is
$$ x^2-mx+ma-a^2=(x-a)(x+a-m), $$
and then it's clear that you need to have $a=m-a$, or $m=2a$, to have one root.

---

The book is saying that since $x=a$ is always a solution, for the equation to have only one solution, the other solution must also be $x=a$.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct and probably the simplest. What your book tells you is the following: it is already known that any expression of the form $x^2 + ax + b$ has only two roots $r_1, r_2$ (possibly complex, possibly identical), and it can be proven that the given expression can be written as $(x-r_1) (x-r_2)$. If you want to have a single solution, then $r_1$ and $r_2$ must coincide, therefore your given expression reduces to $(x-r)^2$, with $r = r_1 = r_2$.